# Flutter overlay with unclickable background

Tags: flutter, overlay

i am using overlay in flutter and if the overlay pop up i want to prevent the user from clicking the buttons behind it like this
[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlPs4.png)
[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCHwM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use ignorePointer like this [Ignore pointer demo](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/ignorepointer-widget-in-flutter-8f975784b9f5)

or you can use Boolean like isShow = true, when alert popup make it isShow =false